# Problem with calling a Setter in JS class

Tags: javascript, class, set, setter

I'm currently learning about getters and setters in javascript classes. Everything works fine until I try to call a Setter to change the value of a property. Calling this setter with the new value as argument returns an error: '...is not a function'.

In the code below, I have a parent class (Car), a subclass (SpecificCar) and an instance of the subclass (myCar). Calling the setter: myCar.brand('newbrand') doesn't work. What am I missing?

Thanks for any help!

```
class Car {
  constructor(brand, year, numberOfWheels) {
    this._brand = brand;
    this._year = year;
    this._numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
  }
  get brand() {
    return this._brand;
  }
  set brand(newBrand) {
    this._brand = newBrand;
  }
}

class SpecificCar extends Car {
  constructor(brand, year, numberOfWheels, location) {
    super(brand, year, numberOfWheels);
    this._location = location;
  }
  describe() {
    console.log('My car is located in ' + this._location);
  }
}

const myCar = new SpecificCar('volvo', 2005, 4, 'london')

myCar.brand('ford');
```

Comment: The idea of setters is that they're *not* functions. `myCar.brand = 'ford';`

Comment: Right, I see the logic now... Thanks a lot!!!